# How do i get the version of Odoo From the database

Tags: odoo

I have various databases for different versions of Odoo ERP. I've spent a lot of time trying to find out the way to solve this problem but i wasn't successful.

How can i figure out the version of Odoo that was used create the database initially?

Answer (score 9):

In Odoo 10, 11 (probably other versions too):

```
SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name = 'base'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider `Owner` of database. Try this:
 Create different user for each odoo version, like user7 for odoo7, user8 for odoo 8 etc.. switch to these user using `sudo su - odoo7 -s /bin/bash`, then create data base, then the owner will be these user. Then u can identify each database.